# Can I feed a switch and receptacles with 12/2?

Tags: wiring

Can I feed power to a light switch with 12/2 and the receptacles, but use 14/3 from the switch to the lights and another switch?

Comment: @Ruskes Do you mean the "/3"? That is to carry hot/switched hot/neutral to lights (which need switched hot and neutral) and another switch (which needs hot and neutral).

Answer (score 4):

If the circuit is on a 15 amp breaker you can use the 14 gauge wire, with the 12 gauge wire.

If the circuit is on a 20 amp breaker you cannot use 14 gauge wire.  The wire must be 12 gauge or larger.

Most newer receptacle circuits use 20 amp breakers, most kitchen and bathroom receptacle circuits are on 20 amp breakers.  Older homes might use 15 amp breakers for receptacle circuits.

Answer (score 4):

### There's just no point to doing this.

If you have 14 AWG on the circuit, **anywhere**, the breaker can't be more than 15A, so **all** the wire might was well be 14 AWG (it costs less.)

If you want 20A on the circuit, **anywhere**, **all** the wire must be 12 AWG. If you want lights and switches on 14 AWG and receptacles on 12 AWG, put them on **completely separate circuits** with the appropriate breaker for the wire size. Which means the lights will still work when someone plugs in two space heaters, or whatever, to trip the 20A receptacle circuit.